# How to read image metadata from a URL?

Tags: ruby, image, amazon-s3, metadata

I want to read metadata of already uploaded JPEGs on S3. Is there a way to do that in Ruby without downloading the file locally?

The problem I am facing is that Image(Mini)Magick doesn't take a URL as a source (or at least I didn't find the right command).

**Update:**

This is working:

```
>> image = MiniMagick::Image.from_file -path_to_file-
>> image["EXIF:datetime"]
=> "2010:07:19 23:07:54"
```

But I didn't find a good substitude for "from_file", for URLs so something like:

```
>> image = MiniMagick::Image.from_url http://image_adress.com/image.jpg
```

doesn't work.

Comment: can you show us what you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using open-uri?

```
require 'open-uri'

image = nil
open('http://image_adress.com/image.jpg') do |file|
  image = MiniMagick::Image.from_blob(file.read) rescue nil
end
image["EXIF:datetime"] if image
```

Comment: Thanks, great! 

Is there a way to just read the metadata without downloading the file (saving bandwidth)?

Comment: You could try to progressively load in just enough data from the remote location and see if MiniMagick will return what you need w/o having to load all the data. I do this with the imagesize gem -- only feed it a few KB at a time until it returns with a success or I've read the whole file.

Comment: @JohnBintz Is there a java library that does "progressively load"?